# highlight CamelCase word

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I attempt to highlight CamelCase word in java file like this:

```
syntax match myClassName '\v(<\u\i*>)+'
highlight link myClassName Type
```

However, `String` in `(String []args)` or `new String("...")`does not work.

If I include brackets `{}[]()` in the match, I solve the issue, but why?

### UPD

[image]

The left one is a java file, the right one is `~/.vim/after/syntax/java.vim`

It only highlight `Main` and `System`, but not highlight `String` and `Date`.

Comment: works for me. Please be more concise in your problem description.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I added an image in op. it seems to have problem around brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, your new syntax highlighting interferes with the java syntax highlighting. There are two different possibilities around it:

1) Instead of the rather complex syntax rules, use matchadd() family of functions.

2) add the containedin=ALL to your syntax definition, to make sure, it can be included in other syntax groups.